# PHP CURL GET request return 401 error (Auth fail)

Tags: php, curl

First I send a POST request with a login and a password (admin authorization) and get some fields.

Next, I need to send GET request to API (check that client email exists), but I receive CURL error: *The requested URL returned error: 401*

In Postman GET request is working, what I am doing wrong?

This is my GET Request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.myurl.com/clients?email=a@a.a");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: `401` means you're UNAUTHORIZED. First try to find out how does your authorization server/resource server want credentials?

Comment: @unclexo API docs: 
"1) The first connection must be done using login and password" - This is my POST request.
"2) If Authentication cookies already saved, you must use them, session in 60 minutes" - This I can't understand... I need to send CURL request with cookies option?

Comment: If you have cookies related to the authorization, send it using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "key1=value1;key2=value2");`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass query string in case GET. 
try below updated code.

```
$qry_str = "?email=a@a.a"
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.myurl.com/clients.php',$qry_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```